# iOS UITableVIew increases cell size on multiple reload

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview

I am developing an app which mostly uses 1 view controller. When the user presses a button it populates an array and uses that array to populate a hidden table view using [myTable reloadData].

Then he can press a button and the table disappears, and with another button it should do the same thing again, populate the same array with the same function and reload data.

But when I do that, the cell's sizes increase and it forces my table subview to increase in size and thus use scrolling to display all the data, while the first time it all fits inside the table subview.

I have probably made an error in the storyboard options of my app, but here's my delegation methods just in case:

```
-(UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"playerCell" forIndexPath:indexPath];

cell.textLabel.text = [NSMutableString stringWithFormat:@"Player %ld", (((Player *)[topPlayersArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]).playerID + 1)];

//display the player's poiunts
cell.detailTextLabel.text = [NSMutableString stringWithFormat:@"Points: %ld", (((Player *)[topPlayersArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]).playerScore)];

return cell;
}

//custom font and color for the cell
-(void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView willDisplayCell:(UITableViewCell *)cell forRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
//set up the cell's font
cell.textLabel.font = [UIFont fontWithName:@"Aka-AcidGR-ScrachThis" size:34.0];
cell.detailTextLabel.font = [UIFont fontWithName:@"Aka-AcidGR-ScrachThis" size:24.0];
cell.detailTextLabel.textColor = [UIColor whiteColor];

//set the color of the label
if(indexPath.row == 0)
{
    //set color to gold for first player
    cell.textLabel.textColor = [UIColor colorWithRed:252.0/255.0 green:194.0/255.0 blue:0 alpha:1.0];
}
else if(indexPath.row == 1)
{
    //set color to silver for second player
    cell.textLabel.textColor = [UIColor colorWithRed:191.0/255.0 green:191.0/255.0 blue:191.0 alpha:1.0];
}
else
{
    //set color to bronze for 3rd player
    cell.textLabel.textColor = [UIColor colorWithRed:0.647 green:0.443 blue:0.392 alpha:1.0];
}
}

//return th e number of rows, should be 0 when the game starts and 2 or 3 depending on the number of players (2 for 2, 3 for 3 or more)
-(NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
return [topPlayersArray count];
}

-(NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView
{
return 1;
}

//create header

-(UIView *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView viewForHeaderInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
//create the header subview
UIView *headerView = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0,  tableView.bounds.size.width, 48)];

//create the section title label
UILabel *labelHeader = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake (0,0,320,44)];

//set it to the scrachThis font and white color and center align the text
labelHeader.font = [UIFont fontWithName:@"Aka-AcidGR-ScrachThis" size:34.0];
labelHeader.textColor = [UIColor whiteColor];
labelHeader.textAlignment = NSTextAlignmentCenter;

//set the text and return the headerView
if(thisGame.gameHasEnded)
{
     labelHeader.text = @"Winners:";
}
else
{
    labelHeader.text = @"Leading Players:";
}
[headerView addSubview: labelHeader];
return headerView;
}
```

And yes, the table is supposed to have a maximum of 3 cells

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just use:

```
- (CGFloat)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView heightForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
```

And return the proper height.

Comment: Embarrassingly simple xD. Thanks